# Add a list per index value in DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Please help my out. How is it possible to create a new column in a DataFrame and join a list of values for every index available in a DataFrame?

For example, i have a df with index values:

```
i1
i2
i3
```

and a list:

```
ls = ['asd', 'qwe', 'zxc']
```

I'd like to update the df to look like this:

```
i1 asd
i1 qwe
i1 zxc
i2 asd
i2 qwe
i2 zxc
i3 asd
i3 qwe
i3 zxc
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want these to be in a single column or in two separate columns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

df = pd.DataFrame(index=['i1', 'i2', 'i3'])
ls = ['asd', 'qwe', 'zxc']

res = pd.DataFrame(list(product(df.index, ls)))

print(res)

    0    1
0  i1  asd
1  i1  qwe
2  i1  zxc
3  i2  asd
4  i2  qwe
5  i2  zxc
6  i3  asd
7  i3  qwe
8  i3  zxc
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just looking after a `cartesian product` and a `list comprehension` can do the job for you (need not another package).

```
import pandas as pd
index = ['i1', 'i2', 'i3']
ls = ['asd', 'qwe', 'zxc']
pd.DataFrame([ [i, j] for i in df.id for j in df.ls], columns = ["id", "ls"])
    id  ls
0   i1  asd
1   i1  qwe
2   i1  zxc
3   i2  asd
4   i2  qwe
5   i2  zxc
6   i3  asd
7   i3  qwe
8   i3  zxc
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've used itertools as @jpp has suggested, but i'll keep in mind this method as well.